# PyTorch LSTM for Daily Stock Return Prediction - Train loss is consistently lower than test loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, finance

I was wondering if someone could share some ideas for why my training loss begins at a higher level than the test loss?

I am trying to run an LSTM on daily stock return data as the only input and using the 10 previous days to predict the price on the next day. Training/test/validation sets do not overlap, so there is no leakage. Not using any regularisation that would impact the training data only.

Really confused at the moment as I cannot seem to find the error.

I will include the code below but its quite long

```
    # Defining the LSTM class 

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from sklearn import preprocessing 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

class LSTM(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_hidden, num_layers, n_outputs):
    super(LSTM, self).__init__()
    self.D = n_inputs
    self.M = n_hidden
    self.K = n_outputs
    self.L = num_layers

    self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
        input_size=self.D,
        hidden_size=self.M,
        num_layers=self.L,
        batch_first=True)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(self.M, self.K)
  
  def forward(self, X):
    # initial hidden states
    h0 = torch.zeros(self.L, X.size(0), self.M).to(device)
    c0 = torch.zeros(self.L, X.size(0), self.M).to(device)

    # get RNN unit output
    out, _ = self.rnn(X, (h0, c0))

    # we only want h(T) at the final time step
    out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
    return out

# Defining a function to train the LSTM

def full_gd(model,
            loss_function,
            optimizer,
            X_train,
            y_train,
            X_test,
            y_test,
            no_epochs):

  # Stuff to store
  train_losses = np.zeros(no_epochs)
  test_losses = np.zeros(no_epochs)

  for it in range(no_epochs):
    # zero the parameter gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Forward pass
    outputs = model(X_train)
    loss = loss_function(outputs, y_train)
      
    # Backward and optimize
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    # Save losses
    train_losses[it] = loss.item()

    # Test loss
    test_outputs = model(X_test)
    test_loss = loss_function(test_outputs, y_test)
    test_losses[it] = test_loss.item()
      
    if (it + 1) % 10 == 0:
      print(f'Epoch {it+1}/{no_epochs}, Train Loss: {loss.item():.4f}, Test Loss: {test_loss.item():.4f}')
  
  return train_losses, test_losses

# Import sklearn's StandardScaler to scale the returns data 
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(data[:3*len(data)//5])
historical_returns = scaler.transform(data)

# Creating the dataset to train the LSTM. D is the number of input features. T is the number of data points used in forecasting
 
T = 10
D = 1
X = []
Y = []

for t in range(len(historical_returns) - T):
    x = historical_returns[t:t+T]
    X.append(x)
    y = historical_returns[t+T]
    Y.append(y)

X_historical = np.array(X).reshape(-1, T, 1)
Y_historical = np.array(Y).reshape(-1, 1)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Splitting the data into a 60/20/20 train/validation/test split. No random split is used here as this is a time series dataset 

x_train1 = torch.from_numpy(X_historical[:3*len(historical_returns)//5].astype(np.float32))
y_train1 = torch.from_numpy(Y_historical[:3*len(historical_returns)//5].astype(np.float32))

x_val1 = torch.from_numpy(X_historical[-2*len(historical_returns)//5: -1*len(historical_returns)//5].astype(np.float32))
y_val1 = torch.from_numpy(Y_historical[-2*len(historical_returns)//5: -1*len(historical_returns)//5].astype(np.float32))

x_test1 = torch.from_numpy(X_historical[-1*len(historical_returns)//5:].astype(np.float32))
y_test1 = torch.from_numpy(Y_historical[-1*len(historical_returns)//5:].astype(np.float32))

# move data to GPU
x_train1, y_train1 = x_train1.to(device), y_train1.to(device)
x_val1, y_val1 = x_val1.to(device), y_val1.to(device)
x_test1, y_test1 = x_test1.to(device), y_test1.to(device)

x_train1 = x_train1.reshape(-1, T, 1)
x_test1 = x_test1.reshape(-1, T, 1)
x_val1 = x_val1.reshape(-1, T, 1)


# Define the model parameters
Hidden = 10
model = LSTM(1, Hidden, 1, 1)
model.to(device)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

learning_rate = 0.01
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Train the model 

no_epochs = 200
train_losses, validation_losses = full_gd(model,
                                    loss_function,
                                    optimizer,
                                    x_train1,
                                    y_train1,
                                    x_val1,
                                    y_val1,
                                    no_epochs)

# Plot training and validation loss 

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(train_losses, label='train loss')
plt.plot(validation_losses, label='test loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your input is properly prepared? You should have an array of 10 elements, not n_inputs=1. I also don't see the activation functions, RELU for instance and would be better to use Xavier initialization instead of zeros.

Comment: I am pretty sure yes, the number of inputs is 1 but the sequence length is T (10). So I feed a single input of 10 sequences into the LSTM. Also, as per the PyTorch docs you don't need to specify the activation functions for the LSTM. May I ask what you mean when you say use the Xavier initialisation? For what exactly? The weights or the np.arrays that hold the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there might be several reasons.

- Your task is difficult, or it is hard with the data you have.
- Your validation split contains very easy tasks.

Another natural reason to this issue is rising from the dataset size, since validation split is relatively smaller than the training split. Theoretically by random guesses (this is somewhat the model's initial state), you are more likely to fail on large number of guesses.

Your model seems that it couldn't learn, it perform poorly on training data, that is undesired. Keep in mind that RNNs are hard to train though. You can try some potential aids like, increasing the epoch size, making the model more complex. If you can compare your results with another work, you should do it. That'd guide you how good or badly you made the experiment.

Comment: Hi, I cant imagine it to be the latter giving the split is done by just taking the first 60% as train, next 20% as validation and last 20% as testing data. Also, since I have roughly 5000 trading days of data, 20% is ~ 1000 days which shouldn't be too small? When I have increased epochs the problem remains in that test loss begins roughly 0.6 below train loss but then the train loss decreases but test loss increases after say 50 epochs.

Comment: You need a more complex model then, or fine tune your hyperparameters and observe validation loss again.

Comment: I am going to continue having a play around, thanks!